# How to check if a string contains a specific character or not in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I am new to python, but fairly experienced in programming. While learning python I was trying to create a simple function that would read words in from a text file (each line in the text file is a new word) and then check if the each word has the letter 'e' or not. The program should then count the amount of words that don't have the letter 'e' and use that amount to calculate the percentage of words that don't have an 'e' in the text file.

I am running into a problem where I'm very certain that my code is right, but after testing the output it is wrong. Please help!

Here is the code:

```
def has_n_e(w):
    hasE = False
    for c in w:
        if c == 'e':
            hasE = True
    return hasE

f = open("crossword.txt","r")
count = 0

for x in f:
    word = f.readline()
    res = has_n_e(word)
    if res == False:
        count = count + 1

iAns = (count/113809)*100 //113809 is the amount of words in the text file
print (count)
rAns = round(iAns,2)
sAns = str(rAns)
fAns = sAns + "%"
print(fAns)
```

Comment: You are iterating with `for x in f:` but then you don't use `x` and use `f.readline()` instead

Comment: I changed it to x, but now a I am running into the error:  word = x.readline()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'

Comment: note that you can do `statistics.mean('e' in line for line in f)` to calculate this

Comment: Also, you don't need to compare each char in python for equality to the letter 'e'. You can just test for its presence with `if 'e' in w: return True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code after doing some changes that may help:

```
def has_n_e(w):
    hasE = False
    for c in w:
        if c == 'e':
            hasE = True
    return hasE

f = open("crossword.txt","r").readlines()
count = 0

for x in f:
    word = x[:-1]
    res = has_n_e(word)# you can use ('e' in word) instead of the function
    if res == False:
        count = count + 1

iAns = (count/len(f))*100 //len(f) #is the amount of words in the text file
print (count)
rAns = round(iAns,2)
sAns = str(rAns)
fAns = sAns + "%"
print(fAns)
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This solved it! Thanks for the help and the knowledge!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Anytime :)